is this scriptable object script for unity correct?
using TMPro;
public class InstanziaOggetti : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ObjectScriptable[] ObjectX;//name of the scriptableObject
    public TMP_Text text;//3d text that will be instantiated above the object
    public TMP_Text[] objectName;//name that will be written of the instantiated object
    void Start()
    {
        ButtonName();
    }
    public void Button1() //with the n1 button I instantiate the first object
    {
        DestroyObjectInScene();
        CreateNewObject(0);
    }
    public void Button2()//with the n2 button I instantiate the second object
    {
        DestroyObjectInScene();
        CreateNewObject(1);
    }
    public void Button3()
    {
        DestroyObjectInScene();
        CreateNewObject(2);
    }
    public void CreateNewObject(int objectNumber)//create the object to instantiate
    {
        ObjectScriptable ob = ObjectX[objectNumber];
        GameObject objectY = Instantiate(ob.objectPrefab);
        objectY.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);

        TMP_Text tt = Instantiate(text);
        tt.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 2.5f, 0);
        tt.text = ob.objectName;
    }
    public void DestroyObjectInScene()//destroy stage objects that have the Respawn tag
    {
        GameObject objectInScene = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Respawn");
        if (objectInScene != null)
        {
            Destroy(objectInScene);
        }
    }
    void ButtonName() //the name of the object is associated with the 3D text
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ObjectX.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ObjectX[i] != null)
            {
                objectName[i].text = ObjectX[i].objectName;
            }
            else
            {
                objectName[i].text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}

I have some problem with this script and i don't know if i had an error in the code or in unity.
the script should bring up the arrays of scriptable objects. I can't find the reason why the objects don't appear after pressing the buttons
Correct my script or send better version of it

thats not a scriptable object, it needs to be a descendant of the scriptableobject.. not monobehavior

You need to add the definition of ObjectScriptable to your code like this:
public class ObjectScriptable : ScriptableObject
{
    public GameObject objectPrefab;
    public string objectName;
}

